# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null while toggling the html element

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
   <button class="openNav" onclick="toggleSideBar()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> 
  </button>
   <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">The Team</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
   </nav>
   <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
    <li>cat1</li>
    <li>cat1</li>
    <li>cat1</li>
    <li>cat1</li>
    </ul>
   </div>

   </body>
    <script src="resources/javascript/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"> 
   </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
   </script>

   <script>
     function toggleSideBar(){
      console.log("inside toggleland");
      document.getElementById("sideBar").classList.toggle('active');
     }
   </script>
```

> Not able run this code.
>   Got javascript error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' >of null at toggleSideBar at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Comment: well it is saying that `document.getElementById("sideBar")` is null

Comment: If you're loading jQuery, why not use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: The getElementById is case sensitive, take a look at your Id

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sideBar` for `sidebar` in `getElementById`. You have no elements with id `sideBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Well the id is `sidebar` and you're selecting with a camelcased id `sideBar` try `document.getElementById("sidebar")`